# New Design Launched

Tags: discussion, design

Hi all,

As you can see the new design is live, which means Apple.stackexchange.com has been officially launched! Congratulations! Also thank you for the [feedback](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268/design-for-the-apple-stackexchange-site) on the initial design. I was able to make some changes based on your input, and I think there's still room for fine tuning.

I have to say converting the Apple.se design to CSS has been quite a challenge for me, it's probably the hardest SE site I've done so far. (All the SE sites use the same HTML code base on Stackoverflow.com.). There are still some known glitches which I'll iron out tonight and this weekend. I know the formatting of the tag-related sections are a bit off, and so are some Moderator pages.

I used quite a bit of CSS3 during the conversion. According to our web stats, nearly 87% of you use CSS3 capable browsers. The site should degrade gracefully with older browsers.

If you see any other styling issues, please start a new question and tag it with [design] and [bug] instead of replying to this post. That way I can track your bug reports easily.

If you're still seeing the old favicons, load the follow 2 urls in your browser and hard refresh:

http://sstatic.net/apple/img/favicon.ico

http://sstatic.net/applemeta/img/favicon.ico

Once again, congrats!

Comment: we definitely need the domain askdifferent.com working, having it directed to a GoDaddy landing page is... embarrassing

Comment: @Kyle - http://askdifferent.com is now live and redirecting.

Comment: @Nick perfect, thanks

Comment: I love it! Jin, you're awesome!

Comment: :-) I think http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/tags/design/info should be created to include a link to this milestone question.

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to give a quick thanks to Jin, Mike Rundle, and the Apple.SE community for all the hard work on what is a very slick design. This place looks great! (Not that I minded the beta design, actually. I'm helping out on Graphic Design.SE and the Beta design brings back some fond memories).

Comment: I second this motion.